# Converting davenport diagram

Tags: jquery, flot, equation, chemistry

I'm an intern at the education department of a hospital, I've been tasked to turn a davenport diagram into a working interactive tool so the teachers can use it in their presentations.

---

I have no background/knowledge in chemistry or equation solving of this level.

---

The Davenport Diagram in question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTphs.jpg (not enough reputation to post images)

I've been on it for a couple of day now and made alot of progression with it, I used Flot.js in combination with jQuery to achieve almost identical clone of it, with the ability to drag and drop a data point, but also use user input and change the point.

Since yesterday I've hit a roadblock, I've googled a whole lot and visited many chemistry based websites just to understand to formula used by this diagram. The diagram uses the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation ([Link 1](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Acids_and_Bases/Buffers/Henderson-Hasselbalch_Approximation)).

Now my first question is, I can draw a data point using the simple coordinate based system, i.e. x = 7.20, y = 8 so the patient has Metabolic acidosis. However, I have no clue how to even begin to build a formula that also incorporates the PCO2 values (red lines).

My second question is, only possible if the first question is solved, how would I turn that formula into the coordinate system used by Flot.js?

Even just gently nudging me in the right direction will greatly help me

---

**EDIT 1: (working solution)**

I managed to build a working tool with the example provided by Mark. Since I only needed a single point to be drawn, I took the formula's out of their respective for loops.

```
            $(".davenportInput").change(function() {
                // replace the , with . so Flot/math can actually use it
                var iX = $("#inputX").val().replace(',','.'); // pH
                //var iY = $("#inputY").val();  // HCO3/HCOmm
                var iA = $("#inputA").val(); // PCO2

                var HCOmm = 0.03 * iA * Math.pow(10, iX - 6.1);
                var pH = 6.1 + Math.log10(HCOmm / (0.03 * iA));

                $("#inputY").val(HCOmm.toFixed());

                updatePoint(pH, HCOmm); // Draws the x,y coordinates
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those red lines are isopleths.  In order to plot them you vary the independent variable against the equation with enough granularity to produce points to approximate the curve.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation), your Henderson–Hasselbalch equation for blood is:

```
pH = 6.1 + log(HCO3MM/(0.03*PCO2))
```

Where pH is `x` and HCO3MM is your `y` and PCO2 is a constant for each curve.  I'm guessing you'll want to vary `x` so solving the equation for HCO3MM produces:

```
HCO3MM = 0.03*PCO2*10^(pH-6.1)
```

Now let's create javascript function to produce a curve with this function:

```
// minPH to maxPH is range of x-axis
// PCO2 is constant for curve
function HHIsoPleth(minPH, maxPH, PCO2){
  var isoPleth = [];
  for (var i = minPH; i < maxPH; i += 0.01){ // produce points every 0.01 pH
    HCOmm = 3 * PCO2 * Math.pow(10, i-8.1);
    isoPleth.push([i,HCOmm]);
  }
  return isoPleth;
}
```

We can now call this function to build out multiple isopleth curves:

```
var data = [];
data.push(HHIsoPleth(7.0, 7.6, 20));
data.push(HHIsoPleth(7.0, 7.6, 40));
data.push(HHIsoPleth(7.0, 7.6, 60));
```

Plotting this with `flot` produces (example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJZdAn16g7VregXpKFdM?p=preview)):

[image]

Comment: Hey Mark! Many thanks for explaining and clarifying the equation, I don't have access to the files at the moment. I'll let you know tomorrow if I managed to build a working tool using your explanation and example.